# pandas: merging dataframes with different keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

df1

```
  1      2  3   4
  101    1  C   22.6253
  101    2  O  -32.7148
  101    3  N  119.0569
  101    4  H   26.8502
  101    5  C  126.1352
```

df2

```
   num1      type   name   num2  first
   101        N     VAL     101  N
   101        H     VAL     101  H
   101       CA     VAL     101  C
   101       HA     VAL     101  H
```

I would like to merge the two and get the following output - matching `first` in df2 with `3` in df1:

result

```
  1      2  3   4        type  name
  101    1  C   22.6253  NAN   NAN
  101    2  O  -32.7148  NAN   NAN
  101    3  N  119.0569   N    VAL
  101    4  H   26.8502   H    VAL
  101    5  C  126.1352  CA    VAL
```

I'm using:

```
merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on='3', right_on='first', how='outer')
```

which is successful in matching 3 and first, but it doesn't do so sequentially, and just repeats the values in all the other columns. Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

```
     1    2  3         4  num1  type name  num2 first
   101    1  C   22.6253   101    CA  VAL   101     C
   101    1  C   22.6253   101    CB  VAL   101     C
   101    1  C   22.6253   101   CG1  VAL   101     C
   101    1  C   22.6253   101   CG2  VAL   101     C
   101    1  C   22.6253   101     C  VAL   101     C
   101    1  C   22.6253   102    CA  SER   102     C
```

Comment: In your result table, how is this coming up **101    1  C   22.6253  NAN   NAN** ? can't understand this behaviour.

Comment: Where did 'CG1' value come from in type column? In your inputs it isn't mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. *I assume that the first row in your result is incorrect.*

```
pd.merge(df1, df2[['type', 'name', 'first']]\
  .drop_duplicates('first'), how='left', left_on='3', right_on='first')\
  .drop('first', 1)
```

**Result**

```
     1  2  3         4 type name
0  101  1  C   22.6253   CA  VAL
1  101  2  O  -32.7148  NaN  NaN
2  101  3  N  119.0569    N  VAL
3  101  4  H   26.8502    H  VAL
4  101  5  C  126.1352   CA  VAL
```

**Explanation**

- You need a `left` merge in order to maintain the structure of `df1` and only add data from `df2`.
- `drop_duplicates('first')` on `df2` ensures you don't get duplicate rows from repeats in `df2`. Note that only the first value is kept for each occurrence in `first`.